# О массовом голосовании

Tags: обсуждение

**Массовое голосование** коснулось лично меня: сначала прибавили 200 баллов и через **пару дней** их убрали.

**Согласитесь, ситуация неприятная.** Кто-то тебя вычисляет, подозревает в мошенничестве, подает жалобу, которая через некоторое время удовлетворяется, а справедливость таким образом торжествует.

**Но только не в отношении меня.** Мне хотелось бы знать, кто за меня голосовал. Если это хороший человек, с которым мы давно не виделись, то я скажу ему спасибо. **У меня очень много ответов, не оцененных никак, никому не интересных и не нужных.** Надо бы их удалить, да  возиться не хочется. А тут вдруг, может быть,  нашелся человек, который счел их полезными. Но системе это не понравилось.

**Тогда мне хотелось бы получить объяснения от системы:** это какой-то сбой или голосовал конкретный человек? И хотелось бы **извинения получить тоже.** Меня-то за что наказывают? Допустим, отвечаешь на десяток вопросов за пару дней, положительного голосование никакого, зато минус двести баллов — пожалуйста.

**Так имею я право получить более подробное разъяснения, кроме отметки "массовое голосование отменено"?** И почему система сразу не реагирует на такие действия, если они запрещены?

Comment: Разбираемся в происшедшем, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В связи с тем, что вам было отдано много голосов в один день одним и тем же участником, система посчитала это накруткой. Во избежание подобных ситуаций следует распределять голоса по временным промежуткам, не отдавать большое количество голосов одному участнику за раз.

Answer (score -3):

Это я пошкодничал. Любопытно было наблюдать, как у участника растут баллы на глазах. Никаких к вам претензий не имею, Sharon. Хотя скажу честно, был бы я более гадким — специально бы вас провоцировал: уж слишком легко вы на все это поддаетесь.

А почему у вас баллы отобрали? Верните, модераторы! Я осознанно их ставил. Если уж кого наказывать, то наказывайте меня.

Comment: Степан, вы можете проголосовать еще раз, если хотите, но не в таких объемах. Система посчитала, что вы отдали слишком много голосов за участника в один день.